# VisualStudioCode error:ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

```
//haha.c
#include <stdio.h> 
#include "hihi.h" 
#include "hihi.h" 

int main()
{
 
   opop();
   return 0;
}
```

```
//hihi.c
#include <stdio.h>  
#include "hihi.h"
void opop(){ 
   
    printf("ssdsd");
}
```

```
//hihi.h
void opop();
```

When I run it on VS Code this is what appears on the terminal:

> Executing task: C/C++: gcc build active file <

Starting build...
/usr/bin/gcc -g /Users/zhengpeizhou/projects/.vscode/tasks.json -o /Users/zhengpeizhou/projects/.vscode/tasks
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/zhengpeizhou/projects/.vscode/tasks.json, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-unsupported file format ( 0x7B 0x0A 0x20 0x20 0x20 0x20 0x22 0x74 0x61 0x73 0x6B 0x73 0x22 0x3A 0x20 0x5B )
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_main", referenced from:
implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Build finished with error(s).
The terminal process failed to launch (exit code: -1).

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

Can someone please explain? I am still quite new to programming.

Comment: Does it build any program at all? What if you have just one `.c` file with contents `int main() {}`. Does that compile and run?

Comment: `/usr/bin/gcc -g /Users/zhengpeizhou/projects/.vscode/tasks.json -o /Users/zhengpeizhou/projects/.vscode/tasks`: This doesn't look right. I'd say your build configuration is wrong.

Comment: As long as opop() does not appear in the main function everything works fine, which is strange since I included "hihi.h" @user17732522

Comment: Then you are not compiling and linking the file `hihi.c`. You need to add `hihi.c` to the list of files to compile and link. (Same place that you added `haha.c`).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.